# Inspecting the registers from a specific frame

Tags: gdb

if you are inspecting a dump, you use `info registers` to look at values in registers in gdb, but can you look at the value stored in registers when the program is executing at for eg address 0x76FD6908? eg I only want the value of registers when pc is at a certain address

Comment: uh, use `info registers`? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I only want the values of the registers at a certain address, read my question

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Registers are not memory.

Comment: oh then just say that the dump doesnt store register values for different frames

Comment: Yes...if you want to look at saved registers, go to that frame and do `info registers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. `frame X`, then `info registers`. This gives you all the registers as they were in that stack frame. Be warned that some registers may not be saved, in which case GDB will give you wrong values in that frame.
2. `info frame X`. This tells you the registers that were saved in that frame alone:

   ```
   Stack frame at 0x7fff5f400150:
    rip = 0x100000eed in foo; saved rip 0x100000eed
    called by frame at 0x7fff5f400170, caller of frame at 0x7fff5f400130
    Arglist at 0x7fff5f400148, args: 
    Locals at 0x7fff5f400148, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fff5f400150
    Saved registers:
     rbp at 0x7fff5f400140, rip at 0x7fff5f400148
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to look at a particular area of memory while running gdb, use the `x` command. This link might help:

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html

Memory examined in this way isn't called "registers", but is this what you meant?

Comment: no i want the value in registers not in memory